# Mouse Wheel in Nested Listboxes

Tags: wpf, mvvm, listbox, scrollview, mousewheel

I am currently working on a WPF project in C# using MVVM. In this project I have a list box that loads a user control for each row of data in my items source.

The user control that gets added for each item in my collection also contains a list box that is filled from a database. This second list box often grows and therefore makes each item larger than the view of the first listbox.

My question is, how to I make my listbox have smooth scrolling. Right now it jumps from the top of one item the the top of the next. Since each item is bigger than the view of the listbox I need to be able to scroll without jumping from the top of each item to the next.

I have used a scrollview to achieve this but the list box then intercepts the mouse wheel event and will not allow me to scroll without hovering over the scroll bar.

Is there a better way to do this?

UPDATE:
I can get smooth scrolling using the scrollview control but I cannot scroll while my mouse is inside the scrollview. I have to have my mouse over the scrollbar in order to scroll.

It is like something is intercepting my mousewheel event.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to achieve what I was trying to do by using a ItemsControl rather than the ListBox. It loaded just like the ListBox control and pulled all of my data into it and let the ScrollView handle the scrolling. It did not intercept the mousewheel even like the listbox did.

If you do not need to be able to select an item, I highly recommend using the ItemsControl.

Comment: Works perfectly for me - a listbox within a listbox was changed to an itemscontrol within a listbox. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can set on the Listbox the following Property `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to improve what I have. Currently I can get smooth scrolling with the scrollviewer, but I still cannot scroll while my mouse is over the items in the scroll viewer. My mouse has to be on the scrollbar of the scrollview control in order to scroll.

Comment: I would suggest you use [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) and check who is handling your mouse wheel event.